# Having Trouble using Cast() and Try_Cast() to convert column into INT

Tags: mysql, sql, casting

```
Update `Food Inspections` 
set `Risk Score` =  substring(`Risk`, 6, 1); 

Update `Food Inspections` set `Risk Score` = Try_Cast(`Risk Score` as INT);
```

The above is my code. I created Column `Risk Score` from the results of the food inspection which would say "Risk 1 (LOW)" or "Risk 3 (HIGH)" and I want to simply associate those to a integer. I need to use TRY_CAST() since some results are empty or have spaces in them and will fail. This cose simply does not compile at all...
[Risk error says "INT is not valid, expecting Identifier"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwMgl.png)

I have tried to CAST as a SIGNED but that lends to THIS error instead:
Update `Food Inspections` set `Risk Score` = Try_Cast(`Risk Score` as SIGNED)   Error Code: 1584. Incorrect parameters in the call to stored function `Try_Cast`    0.000 sec

Comment: is Cast(Risk Score as SIGNED) working?  is the db mysql or sql server?

Comment: `Try_Cast` is in SQLServer, but not in MySQL.  Did you add it?

Comment: I am using MySQL Workbench, and no I did not add Try_Cast, how would I go about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL is quite flexible with automatic conversion.  This *should* always produce a value:

```
Update `Food Inspections` 
    set `Risk Score` =  substring(`Risk`, 6, 1) + 0;
```

If there is no digit starting at the 6th position, then you might want to convert this to `NULL`:

```
Update `Food Inspections` 
    set `Risk Score` =  nullif(substring(`Risk`, 6, 1) + 0, 0);
```

As for handling spaces and other string formats, you would need to provide sample data and desired results) if you want to try to extract the number from them.  A regular expression approach as Caius suggests might definitely work; but there might be other approaches as well depending on the data.

Comment: I tried the nullif statement and that finally allowed me to simply convert the column to an INT. Thank you this was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

> I need to use TRY_CAST() since some results are empty or have spaces in them and will fail

Except TRY_CAST is a Microsoft SQL Server thing and you use MySQL, which is a different product entirely

Perhaps use REGEXP_REPLACE to strip all non numeric characters from your column and assign it

```
Update `Food Inspections` 
set `Risk Score` =  REGEXP_REPLACE(`Risk`, '[^0-9]', '');
```

Hopefully you're not on some prehistoric version of MySQL that lacks it, but if you are you can look to replace all the spaces with nothing and then take the 5th character, which should clobber those where multiple spaces push your number into index 7+

```
Update `Food Inspections` 
set `Risk Score` =  SUBSTRING(REPLACE(`Risk`,' ',''), 5, 1);
```

I recommend you stop using spaces in table and column names, by the way